# Prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 3+4i}+\sqrt{ 3-4i}):\mathbb{Q} ] =1 $

Tags: field-theory

let $\sqrt{ 3+  4i}$   denote the square root of the complex number $3 + 4i$ that lies in the first quadrant and let    $\sqrt{ 3-  4i}$   denote the square root of $3 - 4i$ that lies in the fourth quadrant. Prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 3+4i}+\sqrt{ 3-4i}):\mathbb{Q} ] =1    $

**My attempt**:         $\sqrt{ 3+  4i}=\sqrt{ 3+  \sqrt{(-16)}}$

$\sqrt{ 3-  4i}=\sqrt{ 3-  \sqrt{(-16)}}$

take       $x=\sqrt{ 3+  \sqrt{(-16)}}+\sqrt{ 3-  \sqrt{(-16)}}$

taking square on both sides,we get

$x^2=3+  \sqrt{(-16)}+3-  \sqrt{(-16)}+2\sqrt{ 3+  \sqrt{(-16)}}\sqrt{ 3-  \sqrt{(-16)}}$

$x^2=6+10=16$ this implies $x=4$

degree of $4$ is $1$

Therefore $ [\mathbb{Q(4):\mathbb{Q}}]=1$

Is its correct ?

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}+2...$?  Therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 3+4i}+\sqrt{ 3-4i}:\mathbb{Q} ] =[\mathbb Q(4):\mathbb Q]=1. $  Otherwise your attempt looks okay to me.  You could also note $(2\pm i)^2=3\pm 4i$

Comment: yes @J.W.Tanner thanks for correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to verify that $\sqrt{3+4i}=2+i$ and $\sqrt{3-4i}=2-i$ from which

$$\sqrt{ 3+4i}+\sqrt{ 3-4i}=4\in\mathbb Q$$